# How to find the principal value of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x^{3}}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

The above integral has a pole on the real axis. The pole is of order $3$. If it was a simple pole, we could use an indented path and find the integral. However, I don’t know of any method if it is a multiple pole. I have referred to many books, and they dealt only with simple poles. Can anyone help me with this problem with multiple poles?

The [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1wxS.jpg) was asked in an exam. Was the question wrong, or there is a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I also believe that this integral diverges in the sense of the usual principal value. We are pretty out of luck if a pole is not simple.

Comment: The Cauchy principal value doesn't exist because the integrand is even while $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(2x)/x^3\,dx$ diverges. Is principal value referring to something else?

Comment: @bjorn93 I am not sure, but I think it is the Cauchy Principal Value itself.

Comment: Isn't the pole actually of order $2$ (because of the zero in the numerator)?

Comment: @BarryCipra, but the zero on the numerator would not exist if expressed in the complex form, right?

Comment: @DomTesilbirthShira, the Cauchy Principal Value is meaningful only when the function tends to $+\infty$ on one side of a singularity and $-\infty$ on the other side; loosely speaking, it's a way of cancelling an infinite amount of positive area with an equivalent infinite amount of *negative* area. But your function tends to $+\infty$ on *both* sides of the singularity at $0$.

Comment: @DomTesilbirthShira, your reply comment came in while I was composing my second, follow-up comment. In answer to your question, the zero still exists no matter how you express the numerator. True, it "goes away" if you break the integral in two pieces, $\int e^{-i2x}/x^3\,dx$ and $\int e^{-i2x}/x^3\, dx$, but doing that raises a raft of other issues. In short, I think this is a case of a typo on the exam.

Answer (score 3):

There is a sense in which this integral regularizes to $-2\pi$ which is option $(a)$. We define for $t\in\Bbb R$:
$$
I(t)=PV\int_\Bbb R\frac{\sin 2x}{x-t}\, \mathrm dx=\pi\cos 2t,
$$
which exists in the sense of the Cauchy principal value. The function $I(t)$ now acts as a generating function by defining the regularization for $n\in\Bbb N$
$$
\mathcal P\int_\Bbb R\frac{\sin 2x}{x^n}\, \mathrm dx:=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\partial_t^{n-1}I(t)\Big|_{t=0}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\mathcal P\int_\Bbb R\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\partial_t^2\cos 2t\Big|_{t=0}=-2\pi.
$$
This is consistent with Hadamard regularization. For more information see [A Generalization of the Cauchy Principal Value](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/generalization-of-the-cauchy-principal-value/34E58E1057169989D3CCCD0BCD76B0DE) by Charles Fox.

**Edit:**

The regularized value $-2\pi$ can also be arrived at by other means. Since $\sin$ is analytic in the upper and lower halves of the complex plain we may employ the [Analytic Principal Value](https://quant-math.org/wp/2016/03/31/the-cauchy-principal-value-and-the-hadamard-finite-part-integral-as-values-of-absolutely-convergent-integrals-e-a-galapon-j-math-phys-57-033502-2016/) to regularize your integral. To derive the APV for your integral we simply integrate along the two paths $\gamma^\pm$ as shown in the picture and take their average.

[image]

In this specific example, the integral along $\gamma^-$ is equal to the integral along $\gamma^+$ so we simply need to evaluate the integral along $\gamma^+$ to find the regularized value. We have
$$
\mathcal{APV}\int_\Bbb R\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx
=\int_{\Bbb R\setminus [-1,1]}\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx+i\int_{\pi}^0\sin(2e^{i\varphi})e^{-2i\varphi}\,\mathrm d\varphi
$$
with
$$
\int_{\Bbb R\setminus [-1,1]}\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx=4 \operatorname{Si}(2)-2 \pi +\sin 2+2 \cos 2,
$$
and
$$
i\int_{\pi}^0\sin(2e^{i\varphi})e^{-2i\varphi}\,\mathrm d\varphi=-4 \operatorname{Si}(2)-\sin 2-2\cos 2,
$$
where $\operatorname{Si}(z):=\int_0^z\sin t/t\,\mathrm dt$ is the sine integral. Bringing both results together gives
$$
\mathcal{APV}\int_\Bbb R\frac{\sin 2x}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx=-2\pi,
$$
which is again option $(a)$.